# Use Google Map API v2.0 for lower version of Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I need to use the Google Map API for my android application, but as we are now aware that API versoin 1 is deprecated, I can not use MAP API v2.0 for the lower versions of Android.

So can you please give me any suggestions what alternative can be used to show google map to the lower versions of Android?

Thanks,

Shubhangi.

Answer (score 0):

The Maps API are bundled with Google Play services and are compatible with Android 2.2 and higher. All devices with Android 8 API level support OpenGL 2.0, so devices with Android 2.1 version can't support Google Maps v2. You can check in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api)

**Note:** Note, though, that not all Android 2.2/2.3 devices have the ability to get the Play Services Framework, particularly those devices that never received the Play Store and are stuck with the old Android Market. Android 3.0+ should be fine